# What do the "set_w" and "set_sw" assembly language commands do?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, 68000

I believe the following sequence of Assembly Language code is Intel x86 based but I am not sure.

```
JMPC
SET_W
SET_SW
SET_W
```

What do `SET_W` and `SET_SW` do?

Comment: These don't look like Intel x86 assembly language (at least not in the syntax of any assembler with which I'm familiar). Do you have an example that uses these instructions in some code?

Comment: I'll have to get more info from the person who sent me the question. But she works at Intel, so I just made that assumption :-) However, I know she works with folks outside of Intel who may not use Intel x86, so maybe it is from one of them. It looks like ljkyser might be on to something, though.

Comment: That's definitely not x86, unless those are macros defined somewhere.  The only [`set` mnemonic in x86 is `setcc`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/setcc), e.g. `setg al` or `setnz cl`.  x86 also doesn't have a `jmpc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a few years since I've done any Assembly (college, Motorola 68k too) but it looks like SET_W can be an alias for SETW which is a looping mode subroutine to write the word value (the 'W' part of SET_W) to all components of a block. SET_SW may be for short word or byte? I'm taking a stab at the last part there. Here's the link I found: [RTF/68k Syntax](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/home/fhlevins/RTF/RTF-Chapter2.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you ever have a question about an intel instruction, you should use their freely available developer mamauls as your first stop, specifically volumes 2a and 2b. If an instruction is not in there its either not x86/x86/simd etc or its an undocumented alias. As for those instructions, they might be part of the branchless `SETcc` family, however i've never seen them before and intel doesn't use underscores in their opcode names, this is more likely SPARC or MIPS assembly.